# Tkinter: Geometry working fine with Frame but messes up as soon as Notebook is used inside frames

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a GUI where I have an input/selection window on the left side & an o/p window on the right side. For this first am using frames & then notebook inside frames as I want to have 3 tabs in the first window & few tabs in o/p widow. Geometry is fine as long as it's the frame only. As I try to put a notebook inside the frame it's messing up. Can somebody help me with why this is happening? Also, suggestions for some other way to achieve this are also welcome as I have just started using Tkinter. first pic is with notebook inside frames, while second is just with frames. [image: with notebook inside frame]
[image: without notebook]

```
import tkinter as TK
from tkinter import ttk

#define app
app = TK.Tk()


def init_left_frame():
    left_frame = TK.Frame(app, width=400, height=400, bg='grey', highlightbackground='red', highlightthickness=4)
    left_frame.grid(row=0,column=0,   ipadx=20, ipady=20)
    #left_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    #left_frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

    #have a notebook(tab) in left frame
    #**this is creating problem**
    left_notebook = ttk.Notebook(left_frame)
    left_notebook.grid(row=0,column=0,   ipadx=20, ipady=20)
   

def init_right_frame():
    rigth_frame = TK.Frame(app, width=400, height=400,bg='black', highlightbackground='blue', highlightthickness=4)
    rigth_frame.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=20, pady=20,  ipadx=20, ipady=20, sticky='E')
    #create similar tab in right frame


#init app basics
def init_app():
    app.title('test window')
    app.geometry('1000x550')
    init_left_frame()
    init_right_frame()

# Start program
init_app()
app.mainloop()][2]][2]
```

Comment: What is an "o/p window"? Does "o/p" stand for "output"?

Comment: " it's messing up" is very vague. Can you be more specific about what you expect to happen? Also, are you aware of the need to apply weights to rows and columns?  You aren't doing that anywhere. Finally, you're using `grid` everywhere. Are you open to solutions that mix `grid` and `pack`? `pack` is easier than grid when laying out widgets side-by-side.

Comment: @BryanOakley Thanks for reply, yes o/p means output. Also,  by "messing up" I meant, I intend to keep the input and output window intact, the big grey and black portion as in the 2nd pic. Also, can u be more specific for " need to apply widgets to row and column". Any source/link would be appreciated. I think the design am looking at would need grid on top alteast.